# Java Agent Development Framework - Eclipse and Maven integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, agents-jade

I created a maven project with [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com) framework as a dependency but this framework requires different commands to execute the jar than ordinary java applications.

**Build:**

```
javac –classpath <JADE-classes> Class_name.java
```

**Run:**

```
java –classpath <JADE-classes> jade.Boot <agent-local-name>:<fully-qualified-agent-class>
```

Where `<fully-qualified-agent-class>` is `package_name.Class_name`

**or**

```
java –cp lib\jade.jar jade.Boot [options] [AgentSpecifierlist]
```

---

Is it possible to build a **runnable jar** using maven plugins so I just type `java -jar myjar.jar` instead of the command above?

Would `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command change build parameters of the eclipse project after editing the **pom.xml** file?

Comment: I have built the project with JADE framework but I don't think there is any plugin available for the purpose you are mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any such plugin available for JADE because it is not widely used framework and anyone hasn't bothered to develop a plugin for it. But there is a workaround to run it the conventional way, but this would only work if you already know your `<fully-qualified-agent-class>` names. what you can do is write a class that extends `Thread` and from that `Thread`'s `run()` method invoke the JADE framework agent by passing the `<fully-qualified-agent-class>` as arguments. Refer to an example below.

**jadeBootThread.java**

```
public class jadeBootThread extends Thread {

private final String jadeBoot_CLASS_NAME = "jade.Boot";

private final String MAIN_METHOD_NAME = "main";

//add the <agent-local-name>:<fully-qualified-agent-class> name here;
// you can add more than one by semicolon separated values.
private final String ACTOR_NAMES_args = "Agent1:com.myagents.agent1";

private final String GUI_args = "-gui";

private final Class<?> secondClass;

private final Method main;

private final String[] params;

public jadeBootThread() throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
    secondClass = Class.forName(jadeBoot_CLASS_NAME);
    main = secondClass.getMethod(MAIN_METHOD_NAME, String[].class);
    params = new String[]{GUI_args, ACTOR_NAMES_args};
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        main.invoke(null, new Object[]{params});
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
       ex.printStacktrace();
    }

}
}
```

Now you can invoke this thread from your main method or any other way by creating runnable jar file with eclipse plugin etc.

Comment: Glad that was helpful. Let me know if you have any further problems, I built a fully working uni project with JADE framework.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for this :

```
public class Example03  {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String host;
    int port;
    String platform = null; //default name
    boolean main = true;

    host = "localhost";
    port = -1;          //default-port 1099

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance();
    Profile profile = null;
    AgentContainer container = null;

    profile = new ProfileImpl(host, port, platform, main);

    // create container
    container = runtime.createMainContainer(profile);

    // create the agents
    try {

        AgentController agent1 = container.createNewAgent(
                    "Agent1", 
                   routing.TransportAgent.class.getName(), 
                    args);
        AgentController agent2 = container.createNewAgent(
                "Agent2", 
               routing.TransportAgent.class.getName(), 
                args);
         // create the GUI
        AgentController rma = container.createNewAgent("rma", "jade.tools.rma.rma", null);

        // start the agents
        agent1.start();
        agent2.start();
        rma.start();
    } catch(StaleProxyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }           
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain this