# JADE in Eclipse ICP exception

Tags: java, agents-jade

I want to start writing JADE in Eclipse. To do so I added the following script provided by [Java Agent Development Framework - Eclipse and Maven integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620218/java-agent-development-framework-eclipse-and-maven-integration).

I made an agent:

```
public class Test extends Agent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String nickname = "Peter";
    AID id = new AID(nickname, AID.ISLOCALNAME);


    protected void setup() {
        // Printout a welcome message
        System.out.println("Hello! Buyer-agent " +getAID().getName()+ " is ready.");
    }
}
```

And when I run my JadeBootThread.run() with the following parameters:

```
private final String ACTOR_NAMES_args = "buyer:test.Test";

private final String GUI_args = "-gui";
```

I get the following error:

```html
Jan 29, 2015 5:33:33 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.3.3 - revision 6726 of 2014/12/09 09:33:02
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
Jan 29, 2015 5:33:33 PM jade.imtp.leap.CommandDispatcher addICP
WARNING: Error adding ICP jade.imtp.leap.JICP.JICPPeer@71e070c0[Cannot bind server socket to localhost port 1099].
Jan 29, 2015 5:33:33 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
SEVERE: Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active
 at jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager.initialize(LEAPIMTPManager.java:138)
 at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:319)
 at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:492)
 at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:166)
 at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at main.JadeBootThread.run(JadeBootThread.java:33)
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Jan 29, 2015 5:33:33 PM jade.core.Runtime$1 run
INFO: JADE is closing down now.
```

I tried messing around with the private final String GUI_args = "-gui"; parameters and added "-local-port 1111" but this gave the exact same error (the port in the error also stayed 1099)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following while running your code as arguments in eclipse

```
-gui -host 192.168.2.9 -port 12344 
agentttt:com.DAO.test_agents.PingAgent
```

Then name main class as

```
jade.Boot
```

Then just run your code with all the external jar files added ,i guess this won't give any ICP error.

Comment: Thanks, your response save my time. I forgot to mention the  packages of the agent class

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to check if a another program uses that port and thereby blocking JADE from starting correctly.
You can find out which program is using which port by using netstat in windows

[How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

In my case it was Dropbox. I started Dropbox, closed it and started JADE again --> worked fine this way :)