# Running a jade program without a main class

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have a simple maven project with the Code below.

```
import jade.core.Agent;
public class HelloAgent extends Agent 
{ 
    protected void setup() 
    { 
        System.out.println(getLocalName()); 
    }
}
```

How do I run this program?. When i right click to run it, I dont see a run as Java Application.
I am following the tutorial here

```
http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer2.html

% javac HelloAgent.java 
% java jade.Boot fred:HelloAgent
```

Output

```
fred
```

Comment: A runnable java class needs a method with the signature ``public static void main(String[])``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set maven up to have a run task that executes jade.Boot. You have a [few different ways to do this](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/). Here is a complete example for [Jade using 'profiles'](http://www.ideaheap.com/2015/05/jade-setup-for-beginners/).

For your example above, it would look somewhat like:

```
    <profile>
      <id>jade-fred</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>jade.Boot</mainClass>
              <arguments>
                <argument>fred:HelloAgent</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

and would be executed with:

```
mvn -Pjade-fred exec:java
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `main` method like this:

```
   public class HelloAgent extends Agent 
   { 
     public static void main (String[] args) 
     {
          HelloAgent helloAgent = new HelloAgent();
          helloAgent.setup();
     }

     protected void setup() 
     { 
          System.out.println(getLocalName()); 
     }
   }
```

To run class java `as Java Application` you needs a method with main like above.

Comment: I get that. Can i run this without a main method?

Comment: I've not used JADE so does this work for JADE? If so it would me my preference. The other post for this is much larger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620218/java-agent-development-framework-eclipse-and-maven-integration

Comment: This code is incorrect, you can't create an agent, without an agent platform what allows agents to stablish communication in an appropiated way, this is all done by jade.boot. I suggest follow the link posted by @mlk